# How can I show/read describedby info on click for accessibility?

Tags: html, onclick, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a help link which toggles my `<p id="hlp">` element. Between these elements there is a checkbox area. I need to make help info available (read p) on link click, not on focus.

```
<form name="name">
  <fieldset>
  <legend>legend</legend>
  <a class="help" title="help-button" href="#" aria-describedby="hlp" >Help</a>
  <div class="check">
     <label class="radio">10</label><input type="radio" name="p-v">
     <label class="radio">20</label><input type="radio" name="p-v">
     <label class="radio">Input</label><input type="radio" name="p-v">
  </div>
  <div class="expln">
     <p id="hlp" aria-hidden="false">Help info: Lorem ipsum blah blah blah</p>
  </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

aria-describedby property identifies the elements that describes the object, so according to your question the Help info does not actually represent the help link when you are saying that it should be available only onclick and not on focus, what it basically does is control another region which is activated by this link and is described by the contents of it.

So ideally you should be doing something like this:

```
<a class="help" title="help-button" href="#" role="button" aria-controls="hlp">Help</a>
<div class="expln" id="hlp" tabindex="-1" role="region" aria-label="Help Info" aria-expanded="true" style="display: block; ">
   <p>Help info: Lorem ipsum blah blah blah</p>
</div>
```

So a screen reader like JAWS will now read the contents of the region only when the button is clicked.

And I have marked the link as role="button" as the browser focus is not changed and page location remains the same.

See also:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#button
- http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-controls